# Adafruit 3G Module sends data but don't accept it

Tags: arduino, gps, gsm

I'm having trouble sending commands to the GSM/GPS/3G module from Adafruit. It gives me status data at bootup without any issues (takes a few seconds).

The product in use is this: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-fona-3g-cellular-gps-breakout?view=all#pinouts

The guide says (all be it at the very bottom) that a battery is required. And that might be the case. However I've managed to recieve data from the breakout board, but I'm struggling with sending data to the board.

I'm mainly wondering if anyone else has managed to drive this board without a LiPo battery?

I'm planning on putting it in a car where I have a constant power source, with a 5V regulator that can handle a few amps. The board boots, looks to behave normal, except that I can't send anything in on the RX pin.

Pinout:

- 5V -> 5V regulator (12-18V power supply)
- GND -> 5V regulator/Power-supply ground
- Vio -> Tried both 3.3V on the Arduino, 5V on the arduino and 5V regulator
- RST -> D4 on Arduino
- RX -> D2 on Arduino
- TX -> D3 on Arduino
- Key -> Ground

Two antennas connected, and that's about it.

The code I'm using is this one: https://pastebin.com/N0Yn5udm

And the result looks like this:

[image]

Again, when I send the AT command, I get nothing in response. The I know it's been sent because the internal LED flickers pretty quickly.

I've run out of ideas except pulling ~3.7V from a voltage divider or regulator off the 5V supply and plug that into the JST connector. Unfortunately I don't have any JST's at home.

But if a battery is the only way out, I'd like to learn why that is. Because there aren't much information for this module, only a tutorial saying "That's just how it is".

Comment: Adafruit has a test sketch specifically for this.  You should run that.  And you should connect a battery as the instructions say is required - these things are the repurposed guts of feature phones, designed to be directly connected to a battery, not a power supply.  Finally Adafruit has their own support forums backed by specific knowledge of their products.

Comment: Have you put a scope on the TX and RX lines to see what is happening?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You are a wizard, you got me thinking, so I did. Turns out that for some reason. The Arduino doesn't do Software serial-TX on `Digital pin 3`. But instead, some of the higher pins can be used for this purpose. I switched to RX being connected to PIN 10, and TX on PIN 11, and now it's all working without a battery :) Happy times! Cheers for the down vote (thought the question was at least well formulated and raised a good question/opportuinity to learn.)

Comment: The down vote wasn't from me, just so you know. When I teach microcontroller labs I am always asking "Have you put a scope on it?"

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Cheers for teaching yet another person this. It's probably obvious to anyone who's ever worked with hardware on a regular basis. But to a software nerd  like myself, it didn't come as a first thing to try for some reason hehe. I figured you weren't the down voter btw, it's just one of the trades of this community - getting down votes asap. Anyway, appreciate the quick tip and if you write up a answer, i'd be happy to give you the points for it.

Comment: An Arduino will most certainly transmit software serial on pin 3 if it is undamaged and not used in a conflicting way by something else in the **code you neglected to include**.  You will likely find that the lack of battery issue persists when you try to do actual radio data communication - you might get lucky in some circumstances, but neither the radio module itself or the surrounding board are designed for use without that battery.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson - my heart goes out to the many folks becoming interested in coding who approach these things without a scope. While a DVM is usually an affordable tool, the price of an oscilloscope can be discouraging. But I always encourage people to scour ebay and even local flea markets for a used scope, which may not be state of the art, but will still offer them many years of successful troubleshooting. Always a necessity, since its quite often that things "plugged together" for the first time don't work. And without a tool like this, all you can do is scratch your head and guess. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisStratton, not to bash a dead horse running, but this is the type of community bashing I've witnessed getting worse and worse over the years. To answer your `code you neglected to include`, i quote my post: `The code I'm using is this one: https://pastebin.com/N0Yn5udm`. That's all the code I was using, and am using after swapping the pins. And no, it's not damaged, tried three different identical Arduino Nano's, also brand new all of them. I'm feeding it 2A on average (can get that from AT commands to verity). All looks OK.

Comment: @Randy I used a multi-meter with a built in Hz monitor. Cost around €50. It did the trick assuming it doesn't average out the pulses and you're not testing the output with a "fixed interval". The multimeter did the job and didn't show anything until i swapped the pins :) But yes, scavenging flee markets (or local second hand web-sites) is a great start for most basic electronic projects.

Comment: @Torxed - Something cannot be as you describe.  Software serial transmit works just fine on Digital pin 3, if it is not working for you on multiple boards *then there is something you are doing wrong which you are not telling us about*.  And no,  multimeter is not a valid way to test this. Neither are you "feeding it 2A" - you cannot feed current, only allow it. You might be backing it with a supply of that rating, but the on-board regulator is not designed to pass the needed current pulses to the radio, rather the circuit is designed only to obtain the radio current from the required battery.

Comment: @Torxed My Fluke meter will display frequency too, but now that you're working with MCU,s there are many things (PWM outputs, I2C or one-wire messages, of course serial data of any kind, and waveforms in general if you ever delve into signal processing , either analog or digital, just to name a few).  will make the scope you eventually get the best tool you ever had on your bench. And if you watch for company's looking to upgrade their labs, and posting older equipment on ebay, you could score a great deal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this I always recommend putting a scope on the signals in question. Looking at the voltages can reveal many problems that staring at the code will not, such as

- Incorrect baud rates
- Incorrect signalling levels (true RS232 vs. TTL vs 3V)
- Incorrect pin assignments
- Neglecting to set the TX pin as output
- Excessive loading by pullup/pulldown resistors

If the RX LED is blinking then **something** is getting out. Try to determine the baud rate by looking for the narrowest pulse width. Check the RX line to see if any kind of response is coming back, if so check its baud rate and make sure both TX and RX use the same voltages.